# Performing a digital signature using X509Certificate2 prompt for a password to use private key

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

How can i make sure the C# code uses a `password` to use the `certificate's private key`? The certificate is installed in the `CurrentUser/Personal` store. I tried but still my code uses the private key without prompting for a password.

[image]

```
byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(fileData);

SignedCms signedCms = 
new SignedCms(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, contentInfo, true);
CmsSigner signer = 
new CmsSigner(SubjectIdentifierType.SubjectKeyIdentifier, MyLoadedCert);
signer.IncludeOption = X509IncludeOption.WholeChain;
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer); // Works fine without prompting password

byte[] encoded = signedCms.Encode();
File.WriteAllBytes(signatureFilePath, encoded);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran you code with strong key protection enabled I've got an exception `Provider could not perform the action since the context was acquired as silent.`. This was because I did not specify the `silent` parameter in `ComputeSignature` method and by default it is set to true (so it seems).

When you change this line of code

```
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer);
```

to

```
signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, false);
```

then it will prompt for user interaction when necessary i.e. when you have specified strong key protection in Certificate Import Wizard. The documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.computesignature?view=netframework-4.7#System_Security_Cryptography_Pkcs_SignedCms_ComputeSignature_System_Security_Cryptography_Pkcs_CmsSigner_System_Boolean_).

The default action/level of strong private key protection is medium meaning that user will have to approve (click OK) the use of private key. You can change it to High protection and set set the password if you want (see screens below).

[image: After strong private key protection checkbox is set]

[image: Choose level of protection]

[image: Selected High level of protection]

Comment: It is not throwing any Exception for me. But if I put `signedCms.ComputeSignature(signer, false)` then it is prompting for password in an external window. Why in silent mode it is not working ? Is it something required in my certificate?

Comment: @GokulE It's IMHO silent mode = no user interaction allowed. I did not find any way in .NET to check if one certificate has strong key protection but maybe I just 
 did not look hard enough :)